# Why am I getting a "variable key replaces original key" warning in my BitBake recipe?

Tags: warnings, embedded-linux, yocto, net-snmp, yocto-recipe

Question:
I'm working with BitBake and encountering a warning message that says "variable key replaces original key." I have a .bb recipe file and a corresponding .bbappend file, where I define different values for the same variable. Here's an example:

In my .bb file:
FILES_${PN}-mibs = ""

In my .bbappend file:
FILES_net-snmp-mibs =""

using both ${PN} solves the issue however I want to know why?

The warning appears when I build the recipe, I'm already aware of the solution, but I'm seeking a deeper understanding of the warning itself. Can someone please explain the rationale behind this warning and provide insights into the internal workings of BitBake that trigger it?

Your explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possibly the original [commit message](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/commit/bitbake/lib/bb/data.py?id=05d4f94c25b14ca99a1df01030edc00125f95405) is the best explanation. (In your case it seems to be a bit overly eager warning when it comes to its original intention, but still a good reminder about best practices)